# Response.Redirect in Session_Start doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect, response

I have a simple `Session_Start` code that looks like this:

```vb
Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim sid = Session.SessionID
    Response.Redirect("~/Blog.aspx")
    dim dummy=4/0
End Sub
```

It does not work as expected. Usually in my whole site, whenever `Response.Redirect()` is called, it also terminates the code execution. Whereas here, even if the page eventually redirects, the `dim dummy=4/0` line is also executed.

This is causing me problems in other code called from `Session_Start()` where I built on the assumption that the redirect is an exit point.

I also tried setting `endResponse` in the `Response.Redirect(url, endResponse)` overloaded method as `true` or `false` but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having had a dig into the framework source code I can explain why `Response.Redirect(url, true)` continues to execute code after being called in `Session_Start()` but not in regular code behind.

`Response.Redirect()` ultimately calls an internal overloaded method of `Redirect()`:

```
internal void Redirect(string url, bool endResponse, bool permanent)
{
  // Miscellaneous goings on

  if (endResponse)
  {
    this.End();
  }
}
```

At the end of this method, if `endResponse` is true then `Response.End()` is called. When we look at `Response.End()` we see the following code:

```
public void End()
{
    if (this._context.IsInCancellablePeriod)
    {
        InternalSecurityPermissions.ControlThread.Assert();
        Thread.CurrentThread.Abort(new HttpApplication.CancelModuleException(false));
    }
    else if (!this._flushing)
    {
        this.Flush();
        this._ended = true;
        if (this._context.ApplicationInstance != null)
        {
            this._context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

The method examines the state of the current context's `IsInCancellablePeriod` value. This value is internal but we can see it in our debugger:

If we set a breakpoint inside `Session_Start()` and examine the current context's `IsInCancellablePeriod` non-visible member we see:

[image]

This means that the request's thread won't be aborted and so the code after `Response.Redirect()` will execute, regardless of whether you set `endResponse` or not.

If we set a breakpoint inside an ASPX page's `Page_Load()` event we see something different:

[image]

The current context's `IsInCancellablePeriod` non-visible member is set to true and so `Thread.CurrentThread.Abort()` will be called and no more code will execute after the `Response.Redirect()`.

The reason for this difference in behaviour is I suspect to do with protecting your session state integrity:

> [Don't redirect after setting a Session variable (or do it right)](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx)

If you need to prevent code from executing after a `Response.Redirect()` in `Session_Start()` then you'll need to use an `If...Then...Else`:

```
If <some_condition_we_have_to_redirect_for> Then
    Response.Redirect("~/Blog.aspx")
Else
    // Normal session start code goes here
End If
```

Comment: thanks for your learned and detailed **response** ;-) i guess ill have to restructure my code as u right now, or since all my redirects anyways go thru a global sub, maybe i just put a response.end there? or will that kill the session stuff? i guess ill have to try out these options. thanks again!

Comment: @yisman - thank you :). Because the thread isn't being aborted (I am guessing it used to many years ago in Framework 1.0 but I don't have that version available to be able to examine the code) then the session *should* stay intact. But as always I'd test this to make sure.

Comment: thanks. for now, after u confirmed the issue, i simply added `exit sub` after the `redirect` in question. if it happens again somewhere else, ill add that there as well. not the best, but good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, .Redirect won't terminate the thread like it does in other senarios, but you can still manually add a `HttpContext.Current.Response.End()` after the redirect to stop any page from processing.

Answer (score -1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
public void Redirect (
    string url,
    bool endResponse
)
```

- url  -  The target location.
- endResponse  -  Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate.

Comment: OP already pointed out in his question "i tried with EndResponse as true or false. no go.".